# Angular with Angular Material sidenav and NgRx

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx

I'm trying to use NgRx with the angular material, to open and close the sidenav, but I'm not maintaining it.

My Store:

```
export const sidenavFeatureKey = 'sidenav';

export interface SidenavState {
  status: boolean
}

export const initialSidenavState: SidenavState = {
  status: false
}

export const sidenavReducer = createReducer(
  initialSidenavState,
  on(toggleSideNav,
    (state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        status: !state.status
      }
    }
  )
)
```

my action

```
export const toggleSideNav = createAction(
  "[Toolbar - Sidenav] Change sidenav to true or false"
)
```

my header

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private sidenavStore: Store<SidenavState>) {
  }

  toggleSidenav() {
    this.sidenavStore.dispatch(toggleSideNav())
  }
}

<mat-toolbar absolute>
  <button (click)="toggleSidenav()" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>My App</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <button aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon" class="example-icon favorite-icon" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button aria-label="Example icon-button with share icon" class="example-icon" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

and my sidenav

```
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  sidenavStatus: boolean = true;

  constructor(private sidenavStore: Store<SidenavState>) {
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavStore.select("status").subscribe(
      toggle => this.sidenavStatus = toggle
    );
  }
}

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav [(opened)]="sidenavStatus" mode="side">
    <p>Hiding</p>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

My Store status, changes from true to false when clicking on the header button, but the sidenav does not open and close.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfPZD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyCcS.png)

Answer (score 0):

This may be unrelatd, but you don't need two-way binding on `opened`, as `sidenavStatus` will be updated via your selector and the actions you emit. You could replace `[(opened)]` with `[opened]` as follows:

`sidenav.html`

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav [opened]="sidenavStatus" mode="side">
    <p>Hiding</p>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This would then guarantee that the only thing responsible for controlling the state of your sidebar is the `sidenavStatus` variable in the parent component (unless of course you have logic in your `mat-sidenav` component which is changing the value of `opened` internally).

---

We could take this one step further and replace `sidenavStatus` with an `Observable` that contains only the toggle state you are interested in and then use this in the template with the `async` pipe

`sidenav.ts`

```
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  sidenavStatus$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private sidenavStore: Store<SidenavState>) {
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavStatus$ = this.sidenavStore.select("status");
  }
}
```

`sidenav.html`

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav [opened]="sidenavStatus$ | async" mode="side">
    <p>Hiding</p>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Now, whatever value resides in the store for the selector `"status"` will be fed directly into your child component. If it still doesn't work, you can then at least rule out the store implementation as the source of the issue

Comment: I tried that way, but it still doesn't work